# how to update listview in Popup window in Android

Tags: android, listview, popup

I have one TextView with title All Post.I'm displaying the popup window click on TextView  and populate list view with two items in popup window.And trying to implement this - whenever click on list view item that item will be display in TextView and previous TextView title All Post will be add in listview in the place of clickable item.But my listview is not update on dismiss the popup window.

Here is my code of popup window.

```
      String[] values = new String[] { "All Post", "My Post", "R-Post"};
      ArrayList<String> filter_PostType = new ArrayList<String>();
      str_LastSelectionValue  =  sharedPreferences.getString("filter_post_title", "");

       if(str_LastSelectionValue.equals("NoVal"))
        {
            editor.putString("filter_post_title","All Post");
            editor.commit();
        }
        else
        {
            str_LastSelectionValue  = sharedPreferences.getString("filter_post_title", "");
        }
        textSearch.setText(str_LastSelectionValue);
        Log.e("", " textSearch.getText().toString().trim() = " +   
        textSearch.getText().toString().trim());

    textSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {

                        popup_searchview = new PopupWindow(CustomActionActivity.this);
                        View layout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.allpostsearch_popup, null);
                        popup_searchview.setContentView(layout);
                        popup_searchview.setHeight(220);
                        popup_searchview.setWidth(250);

                        popup_searchview.setOutsideTouchable(true);
                        popup_searchview.setFocusable(true);
                        popup_searchview.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
                        popup_searchview.showAsDropDown(v);


                        filter_list = (ListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.filter_ListView);
                        arr = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(values));
                        filter_PostType.clear();

                        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
                            String str_PostType = arr.get(i);

                            if (!str_PostType.equals(str_LastSelectionValue)) {
                                filter_PostType.add(str_PostType);

                            }
                        }

                        filterPost_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.filter_popup_list_item, R.id.text_filter_title, filter_PostType);
                        filter_list.setAdapter(filterPost_adapter);

                        filter_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                                String selectedFromList = (filter_list.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
                                editor.putString("filter_post_title", selectedFromList);
                                editor.commit();
                                textSearch.setText(selectedFromList);
                                popup_searchview.dismiss();

                                removeItemFromList(position);
                                filterPost_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                arr = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(values));
                                filter_PostType.clear();
                                for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
                                {
                                    String str_PostType = arr.get(i);

                                    if (!str_PostType.equals(textSearch.getText().toString().trim()))
                                    {

                                        filter_PostType.add(str_PostType);
                                        int filterSize = filter_PostType.size();
                                        Log.e(" UnMatched ", " In ListItem Click filterSize = " + filterSize);
                                    }
                                }


                                filterPost_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.filter_popup_list_item, R.id.text_filter_title, filter_PostType);
                                filter_list.setAdapter(filterPost_adapter);

                             }
                        });
                   }
            });
```

Comment: why  my question is -1 marking ?

Comment: Why calling `popup_searchview.dismiss();` ?

Comment: have reference for your adapter and notify changes wherever you want

Comment: But i want to dismiss popup after selecting any one of listview item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
    String[] values = new String[] { "All Post", "My Post", "R-Post"};
        ArrayList<String> filter_PostType = new ArrayList<String>();
        str_LastSelectionValue  =  sharedPreferences.getString("filter_post_title", "NoVal");

         if(str_LastSelectionValue.equals("NoVal"))
          {
              editor.putString("filter_post_title","All Post");
              editor.commit();
          }
          else
          {
              str_LastSelectionValue  = sharedPreferences.getString("filter_post_title", "");
          }
          textSearch.setText(str_LastSelectionValue);
          Log.e("", " textSearch.getText().toString().trim() = " +   
          textSearch.getText().toString().trim());

      textSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v)
                  {
                           str_LastSelectionValue = sharedPreferences.getString("filter_post_title", ""); 
                          popup_searchview = new PopupWindow(CustomActionActivity.this);
                          View layout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.allpostsearch_popup, null);
                          popup_searchview.setContentView(layout);
                          popup_searchview.setHeight(220);
                          popup_searchview.setWidth(250);

                          popup_searchview.setOutsideTouchable(true);
                          popup_searchview.setFocusable(true);
                          popup_searchview.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
                          popup_searchview.showAsDropDown(v);


                          filter_list = (ListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.filter_ListView);
                          if(!filter_PostType.isEmpty())
                          filter_PostType.clear();

                          for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {


                              if (!values[i].equals(str_LastSelectionValue)) {
                                  filter_PostType.add(values[i]);

                              }
                          }

                          filterPost_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.filter_popup_list_item, R.id.text_filter_title, filter_PostType);
                          filter_list.setAdapter(filterPost_adapter);

                          filter_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                              @Override
                              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                                  String selectedFromList = (filter_list.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
                                  editor.putString("filter_post_title", selectedFromList);
                                  editor.commit();
                                  str_LastSelectionValue=selectedFromList;
                                  textSearch.setText(selectedFromList);
                                  popup_searchview.dismiss();

                               }
                          });
                     }
              });


}
```

You don't need to change your adapter after user selects something because the next time user clicks the textview, you are making a new popup window with a new adapter.

If there is anything you don't understand, leave a comment.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: But i have three string  { "All Post", "My Post", "R-Post"}; . If in textview All Post string . After selecting listview item  "My Post" then replace with "All Post" to "My Post" in textSearch  and  remaining 2 string contains in listview  "All Post" and  "R-Post".This is the flow . Thats why reinitialize the adapter in Listview Item click event. But your suggested code wise listview can show only 2 string  "My Post"  and "R-Post".

Comment: go through the code again. When it works the first time, you put 'all-post' in the text view. Then inside onclick, you take the text from textview and except that text, you add all others in list.
Now when user clicks the textView, it will open the listview with 'mypost' and 'rpost'. If uer selects 'mypost' for instance, then the textview will have text 'mypost'. Now when the user again clicks textview, it will go to onclick and then add 'allpost' and 'rpost' in the adapter. hence this will work

Comment: Can you see my edited above post please.This is work only when i continue click on listview item click . But it is not work properly after dismiss the popup and open and open the popup it is not updated.

Comment: @tazeenmulani yes i did. Please first try to use this code. If id doesnt work then tell me.

Comment: I tried your code , but it is not work as per my screen shots.

Comment: @tazeenmulani please come here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112150/android-queries

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112483/discussion-between-tazeenmulani-and-aradhna).